# How to write value on text file at specific position. Iam getting error on this line stream.Write(AscFind, ps, AscFinding.Length);

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
using (Stream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    byte[] fv = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(firstValue);
    byte[] position = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(pos);
    byte[] AscFind = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(AscFinding);

    stream.Position = 0;
    stream.Write(fv, 0, firstValue.Length);

    stream.Position = Convert.ToInt32(pos);
    int ps = Convert.ToInt32(pos);
    stream.Write(AscFind, ps, AscFinding.Length);
}
```

am getting error

> "Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection."

Comment: What is the value of `pos` when you use the debugger? Which line is throwing the exception? I'm assuming the second `stream.Position` assignment, but you should specify for clarity.

Comment: What are `firstValue`, `pos` and `AscFinding`?

Comment: pos value is 36 and AscFinding value is 6

Comment: firstValue is 084960000000*1 which is going well on text file at line 1 while writing second value on position 36 line 1 getting error "Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection."